# JApplet: Never prompted to trust the install. It takes them right to to the error message

Tags: java, security, applet, embed, japplet

I have been trying to create a self-signed jar. I have embedded it on a website. However (this may be a Windows-specific problem), when the applet loads, this pops up:
"Your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running."
According to every scrap of documentation I can get my hands on, I am supposed to be prompted as to whether or not I want to trust this application.
This is embedded in GameJolt's website, so there is no HTML code to be posted.
My META-INF folder contains a .MF, .SF, and .DSA file.
Do I need anything else?

Answer (score 1):

> According to every scrap of documentation I can get my hands on, I am supposed to be prompted as to whether or not I want to trust this application.

You must be getting old scraps.  In recent times, Oracle decided to raise the security level so self-signed apps. were no longer acceptable.

Comment: So, people just can't make JApplets unless they're giant companies? Or is there a "better" way to sign it?

Comment: *"people just can't make JApplets unless they're giant companies?"*  Maybe it's for the best.  By that time, they might employ people smart enough into talking them *out* of deploying an applet.